# Looping a menu after user input

Tags: java

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class Rpg
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        int menuChoice;


        System.out.println("                       =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=");
        System.out.println("                         Welcome to Zest Quest  ");
        System.out.println("                       =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-= ");
        System.out.println("  ");
        System.out.println("                           -------------- ");
        System.out.println("                          |1.Play game.  |");
        System.out.println("                          |--------------|");
        System.out.println("                          |2.Instructions|");
        System.out.println("                          |--------------|");
        System.out.println("                          |3.To Exit game| ");
        System.out.println("                           --------------");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("                       A game by Jordan O'Loughlin");


        menuChoice = scan.nextInt();

        switch(menuChoice)
        {
            case 1:System.out.println("Loading Zest Quest");
            break;
            case 2:System.out.println("This is a text based game.It is based on player choice.Your choices will matter so choose carefully");
                        System.out.println("You can interact with items and objects by typing examine,pick up,attack and other words.");
                        System.out.println("If you are having any trouble with a spefic parts check the cheat sheet provided.");enter code here
                        System.out.println("");**strong text**
            break;
            case 3:System.out.println("Goodbye my friend");
```

I want the player to be to go back to the main menu after pressing 2.Only know basic java and just looking for a quick solution nothing complex.something to do with loops.
Any help is appreciated thank you :).

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Loops are such an integral part of any (most?) programming languages that you'll need to get your head around them at some point.

Comment: @Spangen Haskell doesn't have loops. (Just pointing out that it is *most*, not *all*).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add a `do-while` block :

```
int menuChoice = -1;
do {

    //....

    menuChoice = scan.nextInt();

    switch(menuChoice)
    {
        case 1:System.out.println("Loading Zest Quest");
        break;
        case 2:System.out.println("This is a text based game.It is based on player choice.Your choices will matter so choose carefully");
                    System.out.println("You can interact with items and objects by typing examine,pick up,attack and other words.");
                    System.out.println("If you are having any trouble with a spefic parts check the cheat sheet provided.");enter code here
                    System.out.println("");
        break;
        case 3:System.out.println("Goodbye my friend");
    }

} while(menuChoice != 3);
```

Comment: This worked thank you.But what does the '!' mean in the while loop?

Comment: != means not equals